# Is it feasible to transform Stack Exchange into a user-owned cooperative?

Tags: discussion

Some months ago there was a proposal to transform [Twitter into a cooperative](https://www.ft.com/content/73da6746-e8c9-11e6-893c-082c54a7f539), owned by its users, proposal that was rejected by the Twitter board. More broadly, there is a serious movement of [Platform co-operativism](http://wiki.p2pfoundation.net/Platform_Cooperativism), which aims to transform all major platform that people normally use (Facebook, Twitter, etc) into cooperatives.

SE qualifies for this too. Stack Exchange is a massive Q&A platform with millions of users. Legally, it is a private company, [a LLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_liability_company).

One feasible way in which such transformation could work is if users paid for being part of the platform. Do you think this would ever be possible? Do you think it would kill the platform, and as such, such transformation is not feasible?

Comment: Is it possible to turn your house into cooperative apartments? This way anyone who wants to move in has a reasonable opportunity to live in it. We could also have a cover charge for anyone who wants to come and chill for a while. The primary motivation would be to to prevent you from selling it later to an evil land developer for an inflated price.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Part of SO's *mission* is to provide resources to people *for free*.  Requiring people to pay to participate in the site is *strongly* against its mission, and the values of the community's current members.

Comment: If SE mission is overshadowed by money, by aiming to monetize the site, then users might change their opinion

Comment: @luchonacho: Perhaps so, but you'd need to show reasoning that the current state of affairs is entirely unsustainable or non-representative. SE has been monetizing the sites (mostly SO) for literally *years* in a variety of ways with very little backlash, and while I doubt it's breaking even just yet, I wouldn't be surprised if it's getting close.